# Partitions of $\mathbb Z$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Question**

Does there exist a partition of $\mathbb Z$ in three non-empty sets $A,B,C$ such that $A+B, B+C, C+A$ are all pairwise disjoint?

**Thoughts**

I'm very new to set theory, so while I grasp the terminology, I can't really solve any problems like this with great confidence.

The only thing I've come up with so far is to simply partition $\mathbb Z$ into three segments, but then the pairwise disjoint criteria falls flat.

Comment: Hint: think modulo 3

Comment: @MarkBennet - Given your hint, I tried grouping the integers up by their result mod 3, but the unions don't immediately seem to be disjoint. I'll give it some more thought!

Comment: It's not the unions that need to be disjoint ! Obviously, $A\cup B$ and $B\cup C$  will never be disjoint if $B\neq \emptyset$. It's the sums, $A+B = \{a+b\mid a\in A, b\in B\}$

Comment: @Max - Oh damn! I totally misinterpreted the sum notation. Then it's in the bag! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Following Mark Bennet's hint, in general, for any odd integer $n>1$, let 
$$A_i=\{x\in\mathbb{Z}: x\equiv i \pmod{n}\}\quad\mbox{for $i=0,\dots,n$}.$$ 
Then $A_i+A_{i+1}=A_{2i+1}$ (if $2i+1<n$) or $A_i+A_{i+1}=A_{2i+1-n}$ (if $2i+1\geq n$). Then all $A_i+A_{i+1}$ are non-empty, pairwise disjoint and they give you a partition of $\mathbb{Z}$ (why?).